# Git add remote and push to

Tags: git

I fail to update a branch of a forked bare Git repository from a clone of 
the original bare Git repository.

Create a bare Git repository `repo0.git` and clone it in `repo0`:

```
ROOT=$PWD
git init --bare repo0.git
git clone repo0.git
```

Work `repo0`, and push to `repo0.git`:

```
cd $ROOT/repo0
echo 'First line' > foo
git add foo
git commit -m 'foo: First line'
git push origin master
```

Fork `repo0.git` to `repo1.git`:

```
cd $ROOT
git clone --bare repo0.git repo1.git
git clone repo1.git
```

Work in `repo1`, and push to `repo1.git`:

```
cd $ROOT/repo1
echo 'Second line' >> foo
git add foo
git commit -m 'foo: Second line'
git push origin master
```

In `repo0`, add `remo1.git` and fetch it:

```
cd $ROOT/repo0
git remote add repo1 $ROOT/repo1.git
git fetch repo1
```

Create a tracking branch `repo1-master` to the remote tracking branch
`repo1/master`:

```
git checkout -b repo1-master repo1/master

# output:
Branch repo1-master set up to track remote branch master from repo1.
Switched to a new branch 'repo1-master'
```

Confirm that `repo1-master` *is* a tracking branch to
remote tracking branch `repo1/master`:

```
git branch -a -vv

# output:
  master                107e940 [origin/master] foo: First line
* repo1-master          801d0ca [repo1/master] foo: Second line
  remotes/origin/master 107e940 foo: First line
  remotes/repo1/master  801d0ca foo: Second line
```

Work on the `repo1-master` branch:

```
echo 'Third line' >> foo
git add foo
git commit -m 'foo: Third line'
```

Confirm that `repo1-master` *is still* a tracking branch to
remote tracking branch `repo1/master`:

```
git branch -a -vv

# output:
  master                107e940 foo: First line
* repo1-master          126d61c [ahead 1] foo: Third line
  remotes/origin/master 107e940 foo: First line
  remotes/repo1/master  801d0ca foo: Second line
```

Push to `repo1.git`:

```
git push repo1 repo1-master

 # output:
...
To (...)/repo1.git
* [new branch]      repo1-master -> repo1-master
```

The push creates a new branch `repo1-master` on `repo1.git`, instead of
updating the `master` branch on `repo1` as I would like.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set `push.default`.

```
git config push.default upstream
```

From git docs:

> push.default Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is
>   explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for specific
>   workflows; for instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch
>   source is equal to the push destination), upstream is probably what
>   you want. Possible values are:
>
> nothing - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is
>   explicitly given. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid
>   mistakes by always being explicit.
>
> current - push the current branch to update a branch with the same
>   name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central
>   workflows.
>
> upstream - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes
>   are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called
>   @{upstream}). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the
>   same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).
>
> simple - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added
>   safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch's name is different
>   from the local one.
>
> When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you
>   normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is
>   suited for beginners.
>
> This mode will become the default in Git 2.0.
>
> matching - push all branches having the same name on both ends. This
>   makes the repository you are pushing to remember the set of branches
>   that will be pushed out (e.g. if you always push maint and master
>   there and no other branches, the repository you push to will have
>   these two branches, and your local maint and master will be pushed
>   there).

Comment: Seems to work nice, thanks! I'm reading the git docs, thanks for giving it

Comment: For now I will use `git config push.default nothing` to avoid mistakes, and `git push repo1 repo1-master:master`

Answer (score 1):

To push a branch to its configured tracking branch, simply type

```
git push
```

`git push <remote> <branchname>` is actually a shortcut for `git push <remote> <branchname>:<branchname>`:

Comment: `git push repo1` is also still valid

Comment: `git push` is rejected: To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: `git push repo` is rejected as well, same error message

Comment: There was an error in my example (fixed now), there is still an error message, but telling me to change `push.default` as e4rthdog suggested